# How do I remove youtube from the volume indicator?

Tags: indicator-sound

I've recently installed Ubuntu 13.10, and wasn't aware of this web integration service. So when i visited youtube in firefox, and it asked me to install something to make it easier, some youtube service, i did. And since then, i have a youtube option to control in my volume applet in the panel along with rhythmbox. How can i remove the youtube from my volume?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This OMG Ubuntu has a good guide:

[[How to] Remove Multiple Players from Ubuntu Sound Menu | OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/07/how-to-remove-multiple-players-from-ubuntu-sound-menu)

> Navigate to the following ‘key’ using the tree menu in the left-hand sidebar:
>
> ```
> com > canonical > indicator > sound > blacklisted-media-players
> ```
>
> Double click the closed brackets next to ‘blacklisted-media-players‘ and enter the names of the players you wish to hide inside, bookending its name with two apostrophes (‘).
>
> ```
> ['rhythmbox']
> ```
>
> If you're looking to remove more than one, use a comma:
>
> ```
> ['rhythmbox','beatbox','amarok']
> ```

Comment: I have deactivated all three of the addons: Ubuntu online accounts, Unity desktop integration, Unity websites integration - but the youtube is still in there. And i loged out and loged back in.

Comment: can you provide me a screenshot plz ?

Comment: Would, but it (indicator) disappears right before the screenshot occurs. Now i also have an Ubuntu Music Store indicator there also, and i can't get rid of it :(

Comment: Private, thank you very very much, this has helped!!!

Answer (score 3):

Search for *unity-webapps-youtube* in the software centre

[[ubuntu] How to remove the "Youtube" firefox app? (12.10)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076903)